# Weird output on multiline command in Kitty?

Tags: command-line, zsh, prompt, special-characters, window-title

I'm running non-GUI ArchLinux on VMWare 14.0. I installed a ssh server on it (by openssh) and connected to my virtual machine by using [Kitty 0.70](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) on Windows 10 [Version 10.0.15063].

My problem is: When I use multiline command, the output of command in Kitty is really weird.

---

For example:

On Kitty ssh client:

```
[ddk@mylinux:~]
14:23:08 $ if [[ -o interactive ]]
if> then
then> echo 'inter'
then> fi

then         # not my typing
echo 'inter' # not my typing
fi)inter     # not my typing
[ddk@mylinux:~]
14:23:34 $
```

On terminal in my virtual machine:

```
[ddk@mylinux:~]
14:23:54 $ if [[ -o interactive ]]
if > then
then > echo interactive
then > fi
interactive
[ddk@mylinux:~]
14:24:37 $
```

---

So how do I fix improper output on my Kitty ssh client?

P/S: I am running **zsh** without any preconfigure scripts like *oh-my-zsh*. This is my [.zshrc](https://gist.github.com/lzutao/0ee285ec5ef97a8ae4b0aa7549a000c3).

Comment: Looks like your `preexec` is to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stéphane Chazelas remarked, the problem is in your `preexec` function. When you set the terminal title, you use the command without protecting its special characters. The first newline in the command terminates the escape sequence to set the title, and the other lines get printed.

You would also have a problem with backslashes and percent characters in the command, since `print` performs backslash expansion and you're also performing prompt percent expansion on the command.

The solution is to remove or encode control characters, and to perform backslash expansion to get control characters separately from the characters in the prompt. For example:

```
set_title () { print -rn $'\e]0;'${${:-${(%):-$1}$2}//[^[:print:]]/_}$'\a' }
precmd () { set_title '[%n@%M:%~]' '' }
preexec () { set_title '[%n@%M:%~]' " ($1)" }
```

Comment: I think we shall use a double quote (`"`) in precmd and preexec.

Comment: @DDK I fixed `preexec`. `precmd` doesn't need double quotes.